# Is it a bad thing to pass down a Promise to the reducer and resolve it there?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm working on my hobby project that is made with React, Redux and Redux-thunk.

I have 3 reducers right now:

- attackers
- defenders
- combinations

Inside my action creator I have to dispatch multiple action in a specific order. 
And I need to pass some kind of data from the second acton to the third action. So I did this:

`Actions.js`

```
export const deleteAttacker = id => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: DELETE_ATTACKER,
            payload: {
                id
            }
        });

        updateDefenders(id, dispatch)
            .then(data => dispatch({
                type: COMBINATIONS_DELETE_ATTACKER,
                payload: {
                    id,
                    data,
                }
            }));
    };
};

export const updateDefenders = (id, dispatch) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        dispatch({
            type: UPDATE_DEFENDERS,
            payload: {
                id,
                resolve
            }
        });
    });
}
```

`Reducers/Defenders.js`

```
...
case UPDATE_DEFENDERS: {
            const data = [];

            ...
            // push new elements into the 'data' array
            // update the newState object

            action.payload.resolve({ data });
            // Return the data array, so I can pass that array to the third action.
            // Is it a bad thing to do...? 

            return {
                ...newState
            };
}
...
```

My question: is it okay to call the resolve method inside my reducer? Or is it a bad thing and I should solve my problem in a different way?

Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Definitely a bad practice: "The reducer is a pure function that takes the previous state and an action, and returns the next state." - 
https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions

Comment: In a thunk action, you have access to a `getState` function which you should use to get the updated data in a promise handler in your action, not in your reducer.

Comment: Thanks! I will solve my problem with a different way then. @Yossi